# How to add the Excel argument element to the VSTO Add-in?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, vsto

I'd like to implement the **Excel argument element** (like that one from the default functions, UDFs etc. which allows to select cells manually) to the **VSTO Add-in**.

I've tried the **Excel-DNA**'s *ExcelFunction - ExcelArgument*, however I need to return a 2D array with the unknown length, not just one cell, so this is not the solution.

I've tried Office Add-in elements, but I need to be able to select range manually and send them to the Add-in child form, and I haven't figured out how to deactivate the child form leaving it shown, activate the Excel window, get the data and then send it back to the child form.

Is there any way to get the similar functionality of the ExcelArgument element?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make a user-defined function that returns an array, but then wrap it in an auto-resize macro. [Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) has such a macro in the [ArrayResizer](https://exceldna.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Distribution/Samples/ArrayResizer.dna) sample.

Then you can just say `=Resize(MyArrayFunction(A1:B5))` and it will resize to the correct result size automatically. Or you can incorporate the resizing in the MyArrayFunction directly.

If you want to make a form or dialog box using WinForms for the user to select inputs, and then paste the data into a sheet, you need a 'RefEdit' control to do the range selection. Two examples are http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/06/12/net-refedit-control.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34425/VS-NET-Excel-Addin-Refedit-Control.
You can also search for "RefEdit WinForms" to get some more alternatives.